# How to return child types from a static generic property

Tags: c#, dynamic

I want to have a base class:

```
public class Base
{
   public static T Instance 
   {
       get
       {
           // do something to return new instance of inherit class from itself
       } 
   }
}
```

Class1:

```
public class Class1 : Base
{
      // method and properties here
      public string Func1()
      {
            return 'class1';
      }
}
```

Class2:

```
public class Class2 : Base
{
      // method and properties here
      public string Func1()
      {
            return 'class2';
      }
}
```

I want it so that we can use Class1 or Class2 like this

```
public class Main
{
      var a = Base<Class1>.Instance.Func1(); // return 'class1'
      var b = Base<Class2>.Instance.Func1(); // return 'class2'
}
```

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not called dynamic but polymorphic. In this case achieved with generics. Your only remaining problem is calling the constructor, which becomes possible when you put a Type-constraint on `<T>`.

```
public class Base<T> where T : new()
{
   public static T Instance 
   {
       get
       {
           // do something to return new instance of inherit class from itself
           return new T();
       } 
   }
}
```

and then:

```
public class Class1 : Base<Class1> { ... }
public class Class2 : Base<Class2> { ... }
```

But note that a simpler solution could be achieved with virtual+override methods or with an interface.

Comment: A `GetInstance<T>()` method might make more sense.

Comment: Yes, it might. The code is too much simplified to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative suggestion with some tighter type constraints:

```
namespace My.Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Base<Class1>.Instance.Func1());
            Console.WriteLine(Base<Class2>.Instance.Func1());
        }
    }

    public abstract class Base
    {
        public abstract string Func1();
    }

    public sealed class Base<T> where T : Base, new()
    {
        public static T Instance
        {
            get { return new T(); }
        }
    }

    public class Class1 : Base
    {
        public override string Func1() { return "class 1"; }
    }

    public class Class2 : Base
    {
        public override string Func1() { return "class 2"; }
    }
}
```